# Why is PuttyTel not included?

Tags: putty

Just out of curiosity: why is PuttyTel.exe not included in the All-in-one .zip file on Putty download page?
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about motives other people might have had for a decision that we can not possibly know. Ask the responsible people themselves if it’s really that important.


Comment: I'm sorry if this is not exactly a programming question but even if there's only one person on this planet who knows the answer to this question, he's on SO.

Comment: @CBroe I did email them right before I posted the question. I posted the question so that if other people like me in the future get curious about this, they can find the answer with a google search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoted from Simon:
"Because we don't expect anyone to have a use for both PuTTY *and*
PuTTYtel, so the all-in-one zip file contains the maximal set of
programs that we expect any individual user to want to use together.

We've always assumed that anyone using PuTTYtel must be doing so
because they aren't allowed cryptographic software in their
jurisdiction, in which case they couldn't use any of the other
programs in the suite anyway, so PuTTYtel would be the *only* thing
they could legally download. (I suppose we could easily enough build a
sort of 'Plinktel' - Plink with the SSH protocol removed - but
nobody's ever asked for it.)"